# Возможно ли как то просмотреть глобальные массивы из системной консоли, после загрузки определенной страницы?

Tags: php, массивы

Я так понимаю эти массивы (такие как GET, POST и им подобные) доступны внутри `PHP` кода для определенной сессии, а можно ли как то просмотреть эти массивы и их состояние со стороны сервера?

Comment: Речь о `$_GET`, `$_POST` и прочих? Или о чем-то другом?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev , да вы правильно поняли

Comment: Думаю вам стоит отразить этот факт в самом вопросе ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev хорошо поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// все данные в $_GET массиве
print_r($_GET); или var_dump($_GET);die;

// вывод по ключу  $_GET массива
echo $_GET['key_here'];

Перебор масива

foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
   echo 'Key = ' . $key . '<br />';
   echo 'Value= ' . $value;
}
```

Подробней можно почитать тут [GET и POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php)

Comment: это должно задампить элемент массива, а весь GET массив возможно так сдампить? и куда это потом попадает?

Comment: Обновил свой пример

Comment: И как я смогу увидеть состояние массива если код будет находится скажем в компоненте у которого нет визуального вывода в браузер?

Comment: допишите die; и он обрывает работу php скрипта и выводит все на экран

Comment: обращайтесь, всегда рад помочь